# "Vaccine Advisor" vs. "Vaccination Advisor"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

I am making an Android application which will serve info about diseases which can be prevented by immunization. All in all it's an app targeted at travelers so it can help them protect themselves and educate them.

Now my dilemma is whether I should use

- Vaccine Advisor or
- Vaccination Advisor

The first option sounds like everythng is about the vaccines themselves and not about the process of immunization. What do you think — which one would be correct?

Comment: close too localized. -1 research not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to use the term *vaccination*, not *vaccine*.

There are sometimes multiple manufacturers of a single type of vaccine. So unless you are advising which of the vaccines to choose (not likely), then you are providing information about which *vaccinations* are needed when traveling to other regions. (A doctor will choose a vaccine from among those available to administer a vaccination.)

Answer (score 2):

You’ve correctly identified the difference. What travellers are interested in is vaccination rather than the vaccine, so the second seems more appropriate for your purpose. (There's a question mark in my mind over whether an app can be an Advisor. An Advisor is usually a person.)

Comment: Thank you. I think Advisor could be used in this context - just like Trip Advisor :)

Comment: @PrimožKralj: Maybe. It depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "Vaccine Advisor" might be construed to mean an advisory about side effects, recalls or other problems with vaccines themselves, rather than a guidance as to which vaccinations that are advisable for travelers.